# Are there tutorials which teach you to paint textures for 3d model UV maps in photoshop?

Tags: 3dsmax

Are there tutorials out there which show how to paint textures for models in photoshop with their UV maps? I already have 4 years experience with modeling in 3ds max and I'm dying to learn how to paint textures for my models. U have photoshop with me but the problem is i don't know how to start or how my textures should look like.

For example this is a model that I'd like to practice painting textures for but it is too bland:

[image: http://www.moddb.com/members/timemastercronos35/images/my-first-successful-gundam-models2#imagebox]

I'm currently using plain 3ds max mental ray materials for it right now but it just looks too bland and plain and I'd like to make more stylised like the following:

[image: http://images.wikia.com/gundam/images/archive/1/16/20090808200951!GN-005_Gundam_Virtue.jpg]

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you need to learn is UVW mapping get a complete grasp of how this works and you will start to understand how your texture maps should be structured.

This is a good tutorial that should explain all this - http://waylon-art.com/uvw_tutorial/uvwtut_01.html

Then you should try texturing, using your Photoshop skills to apply textures and paint to your model. Experimenting and practice is the key to this.

But in saying this, I would recommend practising on a simpler object just as a cube (make an awesome wooden crate) or a barrel etc.. This will help you before tackling a full mech, which will be more challenging.

Moreover, that looks to be a high-resolution model, and thus would need normal mapping, which involves creating a low resolution or game model, to which the high res information is baked onto a normal map - this is a more advanced process and equally requires a whole new level of information.

I recommend this tutorial http://wiki.polycount.com/NormalMap?action=show&redirect=Normal+Map

(also in that Wiki there are loads of other great tutorials as well as the forum its self which is a great place for feedback and inspiration)

Good luck!